# error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c

I am working on a project that parses a text file thats suppose to be a simple coded program. The problem is that when I try to complile the program I get this error:

```
In file included from driver.c:10:
parser.c: In function ‘Statement’:
parser.c:24: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:153: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:159: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:167: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:176: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:185: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:194: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:201: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
parser.c:209: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
driver.c:19: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
driver.c:50: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
driver.c:50: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
```

Im not familiar with this error and not sure how to fix it.

Here is my parser.c file which the error is happening in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parser.h"

AST_NODE* Program(AST_NODE* node);
AST_NODE* Statement(AST_NODE* node)
AST_NODE* AssignStmt(AST_NODE* node);
AST_NODE* Print(AST_NODE *node);
AST_NODE* Repeat(AST_NODE* node);
AST_NODE* Exp(AST_NODE* node);
AST_NODE* Factor(AST_NODE* node);
AST_NODE* Term(AST_NODE* node);


AST_NODE* parser(TOKEN* token,AST_NODE* node, FILE* input_file)
{
    AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));

    if(token->type == Id)
    {
        temp-> tok = token;
        node -> child1 = temp;
        return node
    }else
    if(token->type == keyword)
    {
        if(strcmp(node->attribute, "print") == 0)
        {
            temp -> type = print;
            node -> child1 = temp;
            return node;
        }
        else if(strcmp(node->attribute, "repeat") == 0)
        {
            temp -> type = repeat;
            node -> child1 = temp;
            return node;
        }
        return node->prev;
    }else
    if(token->type == num)
    {

        temp->type = factor;
        temp->tok = token;
        AST_NODE temp2 = Exp(Term(temp));
        node-> child3 = temp2

        return node;//back to ID->term->exp then to either print repeat or assignment
    }else
    if(token->type == addOp)
    {
        temp-> tok = token;
        node-> child2 = temp;
        return node;
    }else
    if(token->type == multOp)
    {
        temp-> tok = token;
        node-> child2 = temp;
        return node;
    }else
    if(token->type == assignment)
    {
        temp->type = assignStmt;
        temp->tok = token; 
        node->child2 = temp;
        return node;
    }else
    if(token->type == semicolon)
    {
        temp-> type = assignStmt;
        temp-> tok = token;
        if(node->type == keyword)
        {
            node->child3 = temp;
        }else
        {
            node->child4 = temp;
        }
        return node;
    }else
    if(token->type == lparen)
    {
        temp -> tok = token;
        if(node->type == repeat)
            node->child2 = temp;
        else
            node->child1 = temp;

        return node = node->prev;
    }else
    if(token->type == rparen)
    {
        temp -> tok = token;
        if(node->type == repeat)
            node->child4 = temp;
        else
            node->child3 = temp;

        return node;
    }else if(token->type == newLine)
    {
        while(node->type != program)
        {
            node = node->prev;
        }
        return node;
    }else{

        if(token->type == Id)
        {
            AST_NODE temp2 =  AssignStmt(Program(node));
            temp->type = Id;
            temp->tok = token
            temp->prev = temp2;
            temp2-> child1 = temp;
            return temp2;
        }else if(strcmp(token->attribute,"print"))
        {

            AST_NODE temp2 =  Print(Program(node));
            temp->type = print;
            temp->tok = token
            temp->prev = temp2;
            temp2-> child1 = temp;
            return temp2;
        }else if(strcmp(token->attribute,"repeat"))
        {

            AST_NODE temp2 =  Repeat(Program(node));
            temp->type = repeat;
            temp->tok = token
            temp->prev = temp2;
            temp2-> child1 = temp;
            return temp2;
        }
        printf("error");
        return NULL;
    }


}
AST_NODE* Program(AST_NODE* node)
{
    node->type = program;
    Statement(node);
    return node;
}
AST_NODE* Statement(AST_NODE* node)
{
    AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));
    temp-> type = statement;
    temp-> prev = node;
    node->child1-> temp;
    return temp;
}
AST_NODE* AssignStmt(AST_NODE* node)
{
    AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));
    temp->type = assignStmt;
    temp-> prev = node;
    node->child1-> temp;
    return temp;

}
AST_NODE* Print(AST_NODE* node)
{
    AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));
    temp->type = print;
    temp-> prev = node;
    node->child1-> temp;
    return node;

}
AST_NODE* Repeat(AST_NODE* node)
{
    AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));
    temp->type = repeat;
    temp-> prev = node;
    node->child1-> temp;
    return node;

}
AST_NODE* Exp(AST_NODE* node)
{
    AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));
    temp->type = exp;
    temp->child1-> node;
    return temp;
}
AST_NODE* factor(AST_NODE* node)
{
    AST_NODE Temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));
    temp->type = factor;
    node->child1-> temp;
    return temp;

}
AST_NODE* Term(AST_NODE* node)
{
    AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));
    temp->type = term;
    temp->child1-> node;
    return temp;

}
```

Here is my driver.c file where I am also getting the error "old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition expected '{' at end of input". This also I am very unfamiliar with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.c"
#include "parser.h"




AST_NODE* parser(TOKEN* token,AST_NODE node, FILE *input_file);

int main(void)
{
    TREE *current = 0;
    FILE *input_file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    TOKEN *token = (TOKEN*) malloc(sizeof(TOKEN));
    TOKEN *tok = (TOKEN*) malloc(sizeof(TOKEN));
    AST_NODE* node = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE));

    while(!feof(input_file))
    {
    token = scan(input_file);

        if(token->type != null)
        {
            parser(token,node,input_file);
            printf("%s", token->attribute);
            if(token->checkR == ';')
            {

                tok->type = semicolon;
                tok->attribute = ";";
                parser(tok,node,input_file);            
            }if(token->checkR == ')')
            {
                tok->type = rparen;
                tok->attribute = ")";
                parser(tok,node,input_file);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my parser.h file where I declare my TOKEN and my AST_NODE to create my tree and form my tokens to fill the tree.

```
#ifndef _parser_h
#define _parser_h


typedef enum token_type
{
    null,
    Id,
    keyword,
    num,
    addOp,
    multOp,
    assignment,
    semicolon,
    lparen,
    rparen,
    newLine
}TOKEN_TYPE;

typedef struct token{
    int type;
    char *attribute;
    char checkR;
}TOKEN;

typedef enum node_type
{
    program,
    statement,
    assignStmt,
    print,
    repeat,
    exp,
    factor,
    term
}NODE_TYPE;

typedef struct ast_node{
    NODE_TYPE type;
    TOKEN *tok;
    struct AST_NODE *prev;
    struct AST_NODE *child1;
    struct AST_NODE *child2;
    struct AST_NODE *child3;
    struct AST_NODE *child4;
    struct AST_NODE *child5;


}AST_NODE;

#endif
```

There is one more file called scanner.c but I know its working perfectly because I have tested it in all the possible inputs and got no problems.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: `AST_NODE temp = malloc(sizeof(AST_NODE*));` that looks like you're mallocing a non-pointer type.

Comment: "closed as not a real question" -- this was a completely wrong and invalid closure. "cannot be reasonably answered" when it has an accepted, correct, answer, posted shortly after the question was posed and more than 6 hours before the closure? People should lose moderator privileges for such bad behavior.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Comment: ^ Sigh. MREs are encouraged in bug reports, but there is no SO requirement that the posted code be minimal, and that's often beyond the expertise of the person asking the question. The code given is enough to identify the problem, which is all that matters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
AST_NODE* Statement(AST_NODE* node)
```

is missing a semicolon (a major clue was the error message "In function ‘Statement’: ...") and so is line 24,

```
   return node
```

(Once you fix those, you will encounter other problems, some of which are mentioned by others here.)

Comment: Another way to look at this error, is that it points to the line *after* the one with the missing semi-colon.  And it could be that it is in the included file prior to the lines mentioned in the error... indicating the missing semi colon is at the *end* of a `.h` file.

Comment: ^ Um, no, in this case neither of those is true, and the error is exactly as I stated. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

1. You seem to be including one C file from anther. `#include` should normally be used with header files only.
2. Within the definition of `struct ast_node` you refer to `struct AST_NODE`, which doesn't exist. C is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in the code and What I did is I found out all the changes I have made from the last correct compilation. And I have observed one function declaration was without ";" and also it was passing a value and I have declared it to pass nothing "void".
this method will surely solve the problem for many.

Viscon

Answer (score 0):

near the end of the parser function you missed a '}'

Comment: Wrong. There are many errors in this code but that's not one -- parser has balanced `{}`

Answer (score -1):

Error happens in your function declarations，look the following sentence！You need a semicolon！

---

```
AST_NODE* Statement(AST_NODE* node)
```

Comment: The answer was already posted and accepted 6 years earlier.